# What does "protection of my name" mean?

Tags: meaning

Alexei confronts his wife who gave birth to an illegitimate girl
with her lover Count Vronsky:

> Alexei: You would have no position. And worse, if we divorce, you would
> be the guilty party. That means you cannot legally remarry.
> Your union with Count Vronsky would be illegitimate,
> as would your daughter, who now has the **protection of my name**.
> And this is what you want?

What does "protection of my name" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's about the newborn girl's standing in society. For now, the girl is seen as Alexei's daughter, as a member of his family. If somebody were to mess with the girl, Alexei would be obliged to come to her defense - and any potential aggressor knows that, because the girl bears Alexei's last name. She has *the protection of his name*.

If Alexei and his wife were to get a divorce, the girl wouldn't be a member of his family anymore, and no longer enjoy Alexei's protection. The girl wouldn't be a member of Count Vronsky's family either, she would be illegitimate and without protection.